# Why is $(0,1)\cup \left\{ 3 \right\}$ disconnected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have just learned the definition of connectedness and wikipedia gives an example of a disconnected set: $(0,1)\cup \left\{ 3 \right\}$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Examples). Why is it disconnected? I need a bit clarification on this. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$, the space $X = (0,1)\cup\{3\}$ can be covered by two open sets, $(0,1)$ and $\{3\}$, which are disjoint. Hence $X$ is disconnected.

It is also arcwise disconnected because no path can be found connecting any $x\in(0,1)$ with $3$.

Comment: :How singletons are open in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It's not open in $\mathbb{R}$, but in the subspace topology, $\{3\} = (2.5,\, 3.5) \cap X$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Show that $\{3\}$ is a [clopen set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set).

Comment: As far as I know singletons are closed in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: But can you show that $\{3\}$ is closed in $(0,1) \cup \{3\}$?

Comment: Well, closed in the space implies closed in the subspace, the more interesting part is that $\{3\}$ is open in the subspace. Anyway, this was supposed to be about path-connectedness, or was it? I think the question is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1):

A disconnected space $X$ is a space written as a disjoint union of open or closed sets, that is $X=Y\sqcup Z$ where $Y$ and $Z$ are both open or both closed in $X$ relatively to the topology you put on $X$. For example the disjoint union $\{0\}\sqcup (0,1]$ gives the interval $[0,1]$ which is connected, this is because $\{0\}$ is closed and $(0,1]$ is open in $[0,1]$ endowed with the subset topology from $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Little issue: If you take the *disjoint* union $\{0\}\sqcup(0,1]$, this is not the same as the ordinary *union* $\{0\}\cup(0,1]$. It remains disconnected.

Comment: As far as i know the notion of ordianary union does not exist in topology

Comment: @palio What do you mean by the notion of ordinary union does not exist in topology?